# ¿Se puede imprimir un archivo JS en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo esta duda tengo este codigo `JS` en un archivo `PHP`

```
var hoydya = 
{
    "envio_ur": {
        "transferencia": 2589.11
    }
}
```

Cuyo codigo fuente es el siguiente:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var hoydya = 
            {
                "envio_ur": {
                    "transferencia": 2589.11
                }
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
        
    $variable = "<input id='envio_ur' class='transferencia' disable>";
    $resultado =5 * $variable;
    print $resultado;
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

me gustaría obtener la variable (2589.11) ponerla en **$variable** para poder hacer operaciones matemáticas, ¿como se podría obtener esa variable a partir de ese codigo php?

**OJO** el `.js` no debe ser modificado ya que el original no tengo acceso a modificarse por ello quiero obtener solo eso pero en variable `.php` gracias de antemano.

Comment: puedes modificar el html antes de servirlo? o quieres obtener la variable desde el cliente?

Comment: lo que no puedo hacer es modificar el JS pero el php y html si

Comment: es que las variables "transferencia" vienen de una web que no es mia, cuya URL seria: https://dxj1e0bbbefdtsyig.woldrssl.net/custom/rate.js

Comment: Todo lo que quiero es ponerla en $variable; mas nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor es que, ya que tienes el valor en una variable de Javascript, hagas los cálculos y operes con él también con Javascript:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var hoydya = {
    "envio_ur": {
     "transferencia": 2589.11
    }
   };
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- Creamos una capa para mostrar el resultado en ella... -->
  <div id="variable"></div>
  <!-- Creamos una capa para mostrar el resultado en ella... -->
  <div id="resultado"></div>
  <script>
   // Obtenemos la variable...
   var variable = hoydya.envio_ur.transferencia;
   // Imprimimos la variable en la capa #variable...
   document.getElementById('variable').innerHTML = variable;
   // Imprimimos el resultado en la capa #resultado...
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = variable * 5;
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Actualizado.** Incluida la opción para obtener la información directamente desde el PHP mediante *file_get_contents()*:

```
<?php

// Obtener el contenido del fichero Javascript...
$js = file_get_contents('https://dxj1e0bbbefdtsyig.woldrssl.net/custom/rate.js');

// Lo 'convertimos' en un formato JSON eliminando el nombre de la variable...
$json = str_replace('var dolartoday = ', '', $js);

// Decodificamos el JSON para convertirlo en un array
$contenidos = json_decode($json, TRUE);

// Recogemos el valor que necesitamos, en este caso cogí el valor transferencia de EUR...
$variable = $contenidos['EUR']['transferencia'];

?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $variable; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me gusto bastante de hecho esta cerca pero! sigue siendo HTML pregunto para = darle el positivo no hay forma de ponerlo en $variable de php?

Comment: Podrías pasar la variable desde Javascript a PHP con AJAX, pero luego tendrías que retornarla al archivo HTML con Javascript. Otra opción sería leer la URL https://dxj1e0bbbefdtsyig.woldrssl.net/custom/rate.js desde fichero PHP con file_get_contents() para obtener el valor que necesitas y, porteriormente, implimirlo por pantalla o hacer las operaciones que necesites.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta con la opción de file_get_contents()...

Comment: Gracias exelente xD